# DragonFire SDK NetSend callback not firing

Tags: ios, c, dragonfire-sdk

I am developing an iPhone app in DragonFire SDK in which I use NetSend() to pull one image to display, as well as a bunch of text files which I will parse and stash in SQLite databases locally for quick querying. (This is because the data is on a server with no smarts, just flat files FTPed into place.)  The bit with the NetSend calls looks like this:

```
NetSend("http://some/path/images/some-image.png", ReceivedThumbnail);
NetSend("http://some/path/Downloads/file1.txt", ReceivedFile1);
NetSend("http://some/path/Downloads/file2.txt", ReceivedFile2);
NetSend("http://some/path/Downloads/file3.txt", ReceivedFile3);
NetSend("http://some/path/Downloads/file4.txt", ReceivedFile4);
NetSend("http://some/path/Downloads/file5.txt", ReceivedFile5);
```

Obviously I've changed the filenames and everything, to protect the innocent. Here's an example of one of the callbacks:

```
int ReceivedThumbnail(int event, char *response, int length) {
  printf("ReceivedThumbnail\n");
  if (event == 0) return 0;
  FileDelete("Thumbnail.png");
  int ThumbnailFile = FileCreate("Thumbnail.png");
  FileWrite(ThumbnailFile, response, length);
  FileClose(ThumbnailFile);
  return 0;
}
```

I've confirmed that the NetSend block is being executed, and the files are present on the web server, but most of the time the callbacks never fire. Some of them haven't been written yet so contain nothing but the printf() but it never happens.

Oddly, after getting frustrated with this yesterday and going to do something else, when I came back this morning to try again, one of them *did* run, just enough for me to see a bug in the code. I fixed the bug, but now it won't run again. The file in question is updated daily, so I wonder, is there some kind of caching going on in NetSend that, if the file hasn't been updated since a NetSend ran before for it, it won't fire the callback? If so, is there a way to disable or override that? (I can see how it could be good to have in production; in fact, I wrote my own caching code already to avoid calling NetSend at all, though it's currently disabled. But while I'm developing the code, I need to get this callback to keep happening until I've got the data into the SQLite correctly.)

Any other ideas for what to check?

Comment: I tried writing some code that makes a fakely unique URL by adding ?t=<stuff> to the end (I use a date/timestamp to make sure it's unique) to see if that would make it work, but the callbacks still aren't firing.  I confirmed that these fake URLs do give me the right results in a browser.  Does that mean it has nothing to do with caching, or that the caching isn't fooled by me adding this string to the end?

Comment: The callbacks aren't running at all today so the file update at 6:30am no longer seems relevant. I made a fresh new app with nothing but the NetSend call and the callback, both doing just printf()s, and the callback still doesn't fire, so it can't be anything else in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard back from the DragonFire support team and found out the answer. The problem is that while NetSend() calls are creating threads, each NetSend() *cancels* the previous one, so the benefits of multithreading are lost. Thus, to do a set of NetSend()s like this, you need to make a "daisy chain" where the callback from the first one does whatever it has to do and then starts another NetSend() for the second one, whose callback starts the third, etc. and the final callback then calls a "main" function (not AppMain() of course). It makes my source code a little harder to follow, of course, but it seems to work.

DragonFire Support agreed that this is the sort of thing that should be, but isn't, in the API documentation, so hopefully it will be in a future version.